# Make part of a string bold with Regex and PHP

Tags: php, regex

My problem is, that I need a part of a string bold. In my case **6000 Luzern**. It's the zip-code and the town-name.

```
<?php
$pattern = '/[0-9]{4}.*(?=,)/';
$replacement = '<strong>'.$pattern.'</strong>';
$subject = 'Hello 6000 Luzern, 0586464129';
echo preg_replace($pattern , $replacement , $subject);
?>
```

Result:
Hallo **/[0-9]{4}.*(?=,)/,** 5564641

The code is realising, what part I need, but how can it bold it?
It should be like this:

Hello **6000 Luzern**, 5564641

Comment: Use html tags in your replacement argument ?!

Comment: What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your regex as:

```
$pattern = '/\b[0-9]{4}[^,]+\b/';
```

and replacement with `$0` (matched string):

```
$replacement = '<strong>$0</strong>';
```

as you need to use matched back-reference in the replacement as well.

Now code:

```
echo preg_replace($pattern , $replacement , $subject);
//=> Hello <strong>6000 Luzern</strong>, <strong>0586464129</strong>
```

Regex `\b[0-9]{4}[^,]+\b` matches:

```
\b       # word boundary
[0-9]{4} # 4 digits
[^,]+    # 1 or more of non-comma chars
\b       # word boundary
```

Comment: Thanks a lot anubhava. I use the following: $pattern = '/[0-9]{4}.*(?=,)/';

Comment: It works perfect for my case. Thanks for explanations too ;-)

Comment: I found another pattern, that matches even more straighter:
$pattern = '/[0-9]{4}.([A-Z])\w+/';
In some cases, the other pattern did not stop at the first comma. Hope that helps also somebody else.

Comment: @anubhava can you answer my question if you have a time please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895399/editing-text-like-whatsapp-in-php