# Replace pairs of symbols in chat text with html tags to style as bold, italic, and strikethrough

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, preg-replace

I am trying to make a whatsapp style text post. When user create text like this:

```
*Hi* ~how are you~ _where are you?_
```

then this text is automatically changing like this

**Hi** how are you *where are you*

I know i can do it with php regex like this:

The example is for bold text:

```
function makeBoldText($orimessage){
    $message = $orimessage;
    $regex = "/\*([\w]*)\*/";
    $message = preg_replace($regex, '<strong>$0</strong>', $message);
    return  $message ;
}
echo makeBoldText($message);
```

But there is a problem it should be remove `*` when text is outputed.

The other regex also should be like this:

Bold:

```
/\*([\w]*)\*/
```

Italic:

```
/_([\w]*)_/
```

strikethrough:

```
 /~([\w]*)~/
```

**My question is, can I do all this in one regex? And can the special characters be deleted when the output is made?**

Comment: That's basically just [markdown](http://kirkstrobeck.github.io/whatismarkdown.com/). Use some library to parse that. It's not as easy as you might think. There are _many_ rules you need to consider otherwise.

Comment: This shouldn't be done in the backend as you don't really want to store HTML in the database. HTML can be much larger than Markdown. Apart from that, you should let your users edit their original content which is in Markdown, right? Think about that.

Comment: @Victor How do you think you might encounter a problem? I just want to get the image in three different ways. bold, italic and strikethrough. I don't want anything else. also thanks to anubhava 's answer was solved.

Comment: I am just saying this is something like only keeping minified JavaScript in your repository

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use a single call to `preg_replace_callback` here:

```
$styles = array ( '*' => 'strong', '_' => 'i', '~' => 'strike');

function makeBoldText($orimessage) {
   global $styles;
   return preg_replace_callback('/(?<!\w)([*~_])(.+?)\1(?!\w)/',
      function($m) use($styles) { 
         return '<'. $styles[$m[1]]. '>'. $m[2]. '</'. $styles[$m[1]]. '>';
      },
      $orimessage);
}

// call it as:
$s = '*Hi* ~how are you~ _where are you?_';
echo makeBoldText($s);
//=> <strong>Hi</strong> <strike>how are you</strike> <i>where are you?</i>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer dear. But the codes are a little complicated for me. I couldn't understand how to use it.

Comment: can you show me how can i use your answer in my `function makeBoldText($orimessage){..... }` please ?

Comment: Dear can you check this screenshot for me i am doing wrong somewhere ? https://prnt.sc/lydkqc

Comment: Can you answer my question please, if you have a time Dear anubhava ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906690/ajax-if-more-then-one-mention?noredirect=1#comment94658173_53906690 i really need help

Comment: Dear your answer is working but there something missing. For example if i wrote mention like `@husey_in` the username is husey_in your code also working for usernames it is replacing i like `@husey_<i>in</i>` it should work for when `_text_` between `_ ` or `~`or `*`

Comment: your answer should work for before first letter and last letter. If i write `_hi how are you_` then is should work but if i wrote `hi_bro_how_are_you` then it should not work. also same think for other characters `*~`

Comment: Dear i get this now `Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Unknown modifier '('` from `$orimessage);`

Comment: Dear what do you think about `@victor` comment ?

Comment: i don't need to enable it just want to allow italic, bold and strikethrough other think are not for my project. For example facebook doing this when you write text in a star like this `*Hi stackoverflow*` then the text is automatically bold. Also whatsapp doing this. I don't need other editable feature. So I don't want users to do anything other than this.

Comment: so do you mean facebook and whatsapp showing the html storing from database like. `<i>Stackoverflow</i>` ?

Comment: stackoverflow doing this also i think or not ? When we want bold text we write `*` before text and after text .

Comment: Dear do you know there is a way to do your answer via jquery regex ?

Comment: Dear can i ask you one little question ?

Comment: is there anyway to change the url `website.com/username` to `username.website.com/` without creating a subdomain. I see the tumblr doing this but how they did it i don't know. I just thinking maybe we can do it with htaccess ?

Comment: here is the link for example: `https://lovefirthlove.tumblr.com/` . When you register tumblr then your profile link looks like this : `https://anubhava.tumblr.com/`

Comment: I think this is done through `VirtualHost` config, not from .htaccess but I have little knowledge in that.

Comment: how can i do that dear. Is there any tutorial about it or can you expalin me please?

Comment: As I said I have little knowledge as I am not an admin, you will need to search on net.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't know if it is possible to do it all in one regex, but for your second question: *"can the special characters be deleted when the output is made"*, you can do something like this:

```
$subject = "*Hi* ~how are you~ _where are you?_";
$message = preg_replace('/(?:\*)([^*]*)(?:\*)/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $subject);
$message = preg_replace('/(?:_)([^_]*)(?:_)/', '<i>$1</i>', $message);
$message = preg_replace('/(?:~)([^~]*)(?:~)/', '<strike>$1</strike>', $message);
```

---

As [emi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7729561/emi) commented, you can use `<b>` for bold, `<i>` for italic and `<s>` for strike

Comment: This work for me. I don't know why Azzo needs all in the same regex; but ignoring that, this should be the correct approach because let you use nested styles (meanwhile the current accepted answer doesn't)

Comment: Only one call of `preg_replace()` is necessary because the function can receive an array in the first and second argument.

Comment: You can do the same thing on javascript at here using one UDF function of javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65787617/how-to-format-your-messages-like-whatsapp-on-javascript

Answer (score 4):

Although this question is about PHP, however, this is javascript equivalent. Also many people want a perfect code that will fit their needs.
If you don't want styling to span through new line and also using `([^*<\n]+)` makes sure at least one character is in between styles or else `**` without a character in-between will result will become invisible.

````
function format_text(text){
return text.replace(/(?:\*)([^*<\n]+)(?:\*)/g, "<strong>$1</strong>")
     .replace(/(?:_)([^_<\n]+)(?:_)/g, "<i>$1</i>")
      .replace(/(?:~)([^~<\n]+)(?:~)/g, "<s>$1</s>")
      .replace(/(?:```)([^```<\n]+)(?:```)/g, "<tt>$1</tt>")
}
````

•The downside to the above code is that, you can't nest styles i.e  `*_Bold and italic_*`

To allow nested styles use this

````
function format_text(text){
return text.replace(/(?:\*)(?:(?!\s))((?:(?!\*|\n).)+)(?:\*)/g,'<b>$1</b>')
   .replace(/(?:_)(?:(?!\s))((?:(?!\n|_).)+)(?:_)/g,'<i>$1</i>')
   .replace(/(?:~)(?:(?!\s))((?:(?!\n|~).)+)(?:~)/g,'<s>$1</s>')
   .replace(/(?:--)(?:(?!\s))((?:(?!\n|--).)+)(?:--)/g,'<u>$1</u>')
   .replace(/(?:```)(?:(?!\s))((?:(?!\n|```).)+)(?:```)/g,'<tt>$1</tt>');

// extra:
// --For underlined text--
// ```Monospace font```
}
````

If you want your style to span through new line, then remove `\n`  from the regex. Also if your new line is html break tag, you can replace `\n` with `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing on javascript at here using one UDF function of javascript

Use this function to wrap your text using regular expression (regex).

````js
function wrap(str) {
  if (str) {
    return str
      .replace(/(?:\*)([^*]*)(?:\*)/gm, "<strong>$1</strong>")
      .replace(/(?:_)([^_]*)(?:_)/gm, "<i>$1</i>")
      .replace(/(?:~)([^~]*)(?:~)/gm, "<strike>$1</strike>")
      .replace(/(?:```)([^```]*)(?:```)/gm, "<tt>$1</tt>");
  } else {
    return str;
  }
}
let str="Hello *Hiren Raiyani*, This is testing text which has _italic_ text and ~Strick Text~ also, and ``` monospace text also exists ```"; 

let htmlStr = wrap(str);
console.log(htmlStr);

document.getElementById("str-wrp").innerHTML = htmlStr;
````

```html
<div id="str-wrp"></div>
```

Example:

````
let str="Hello *Hiren Raiyani*, This is testing text which has _italic_ text and ~Strick Text~ also, and ``` monospace text also exists ```;

wrap(str);
````

Output:

```
Hello <strong>Hiren</strong>, This is testing text which has <i>italic</i> text and <strick>Strick Text</strick> also, and <tt> monospace text also exists <tt>
```